# Firefox server error

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, firefox

For the past day or two, I have been tinkering and setting up my new Linux software. I uploaded Ubuntu onto my old Windows XP, and now the wifi won't work.

Here's a run through of what's happening:

- I start up the computer.
- My Wifi automatically connects to my computer with full bars.
- I open Firefox. I google Reddit or I put it into the URL bar. The exact moment I press enter, my wifi turns off and disconnects.
- I go to the network menu and click "connect to a hidden network." I connect to my home's Wifi and it works. A few seconds later it turns off again.
- I go on to Ask Ubuntu and look for answers, type a few commands into the terminal and nothing works.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Keep in mind that every other device in my house works.

`lspci` results:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 01)
```

Wireless info: http://pastebin.com/6eKP1ik7

Note: I'm not having the on and off wifi problem now. My adapter was just overheating. I'm still having the server problem though.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Hey mikewhatever. Thanks for the code! I tried typing it into my terminal and it gave me this error: "Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Name or service not known. wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com'

Comment: You're supposed to have a working alternative internet connection for downloading the script. If not, in the same accepted answer, there are instructions you should read also. That said, in order to simplify things, you can run lspci in terminal and then post the relevant line pertaining to the specific device you have in the new one. It seems you're under the impression there are generic wifi drivers. That's not the case, different hardware, different drivers.

Comment: Hi @CelticWarrior. I did read the instructions for if I didn't. I also followed them and I got the error that I told mikewhatever about. I also tried to run ispci in the terminal (I used the information given to me by other ubuntu troubleshooting forums, so correct me if I'm wrong.) and it told me that no command called ispci exists.

Comment: You're still not understanding that downloading (wget) requires internet. If not available you need to download the files from another online device and then run the script in the one offline. And please pay attention and copy/paste to avoid errors. For example, the command above is **lspci**, with an L.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yeah sorry about that... I have the information from lspci but not the one from the script mikewhatever sent me. Sorry to be a pain, but I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm having difficulty executing the script. Could you tell me what I did wrong? I typed this into the terminal: 'sh wireless-info.sh' (without the quotation marks of course) and this was the output: 'sh: 0: Can't open wireless-info.sh'. Also, should I post it here in the comments or in another post with the information they gave me? Thanks!

Comment: Either copy the file to `/home/your_username` (where the terminal opens by default) or you have to `cd` into the folder where it resides before running it and all you have to do then, either way, is the second and third parts of the command, i.e., `chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`. But the `lspci`  results you can post meanwhile, by **editing** your question.

Comment: Oh my god yes! It worked! Thanks! I'm uploading everything now. @CelticWarrior

Comment: What server problem do you mean? I don't see that you've mentioned one in the question or in the comments.

Comment: FYI, "upload" means to send data to a remote computer. "Install" is the word you want.

Comment: @wjandrea When I opened firefox or any other browser, it would tell me that there was a server error and that I needed to check my network connection. Also, you misunderstood me when I said upload. I already installed and downloaded the script. By upload, I mean uploading the information to paste bin.

Comment: @FrankGallagher Oh, right, I meant in your question when you said you "uploaded Ubuntu".

Comment: @FrankGallagher Regarding the server error, that sounds like a separate issue, since the wifi is now working. You may want to ask a new question.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I don't know why I said upload.

Comment: @FrankGallagher The new title doesn't reflect the question. As I said, the server error is a separate issue, so you should ask a new question.

Comment: @wjandrea As stated in the note, the problem with the in-and-out wifi was solved. It was an overheating adapter. You added that into the title, so I fixed it.